# $.get / $ post jquery function to manipulate a function from another file(*.html)

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario like the one I described below...

how can I accomplish by using $.get / $ post jquery function ?

**Send.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () 
        {
            $("#btn").click(function() {
            Receive.ShowMsg("Heloword"); // 
            });

    </script>   

<body>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="SendMessage">
</body>
```

**Receive.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowMsg (strtext)
{
$("#result").val(strtext);
}           
</script>

<body>
<div class="input"> <input type="text" id="result"></input> </div>
</body>
```

thank's in advance

Comment: what is the usage of this? you want to set a value to non opened page in current page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want changes in a certain page to reflect on another page, I suggest you build an intermediate server script (e.g. in PHP), with a database backend or other storage system. One page pushes its results to the server, while the other pulls the needed information from the server. I don't think there is a way to have seperate pages in a browser directly communicate with each other, except under certain circumstances (like iframes or child windows).

Comment: my goal is how to manipulate ShowMsg function with  $.post( url, [data], [callback], [type] ) jquery method.. then load and display the Receive.html on iframes....can you give me a sample what parameters should i pass to the method